# Link time running of code? (specifically, issues raised by Valgrind seemingly at linktime)

Tags: c, linux, opencl, valgrind, shared-libraries

I suspect this is an issue with my understanding of how the linking of shared objects takes place on Linux.

Using Valgrind with OpenCL (which, from various other posts, I understand to be problematic in its own right), I'm encountering errors from a module that is part of the shared object but is never actually run.

Specifically, I have an OpenCL helper module that has a series of functions for performing OpenCL actions. I have removed all references to the functions within this module from the executing code. I would naively assume, therefore, that this module cannot raise any problems with Valgrind.

However, I *am* seeing issues that are raised through `_dl_init.c` (lots of them, showing how broken OpenCL is with Valgrind). This suggests to me that code within the OpenCL runtime is being executed at link time.

Can someone clarify (or point me to suitable clarification material) how `_dl_init.c` is involved in the linker process?

Is it universally true that the `.so` files execute some initialisation code, or is it a library option?

Is this something that is easily accessible to library writers, or does it involved nefarious hacks?

Comment: Shared libraries can have dependencies (other libraries that are invoked at runtime), which is what it appears you are asking.  Try using the ldd command on some shared libraries in /lib.  nm [filename.so] will show there are external symbols in the library, too.

Comment: @jimmcnamara of course, though I would not normally expect code from the dependency to be invoked unless calls were made to the initial library. The issue I'm having is that code is being _executed_ within the shared library without any trigger from my code beyond being linked to it (which is causing issues for Valgrind) and I don't understand how this code is being invoked. It seems to be through `_dl_init.c` in `ld-2.17.so`, hence the assumption it is happening at link-time. My question is, what is the process by which this happens?

Comment: Exectuing - that is what I'm talking about. A module is instantiated and runs, maybe even in another thread or process.  I think you and I are talking past one another.  Probably some implicit assumption. Suppose libA gets invoked. It has a dependency on libB, which also gets invoked.  Now, libB, which you have not looked at, needs to invoke _dl_init.c, so it runs the code that lives in libA. Or in libC. Run fuser or lsof on your process to see what is really open.

Comment: Any entry point in a library is fair game once the library is opened.  cYou do NOT have to explicitly reference that entry point in your code in order for it to run.  OpenCL is kind of a mess, so that means circular references are not out of the question, as well

Comment: So, my question is, why is libA invoked at all? I have no entry defined into libA, but it is still being executed in some sense (yes, such that some other lib _it_ invokes is breaking). Do you know about `_dl_init.c` and so can enlighten me? :)

Comment: @jimmcnamara you say that "You do NOT have to explicitly reference that entry point in your code in order for it to run". This is the essence of my question... What causes code to run that I don't explicitly request to run?

Comment: A reference tree. You call strftime() which in turn calls sprintf().  You never explictly call sprintf() in your code, yet it runs anyway.  Because strftime() referenced it - you did not.

Comment: @jimmcnamara Ok, but I'm never calling _anything_ that calls into libOpenCL. The first thing I did in investigating this was to strip out all calls to anything that make invoke that library (either directly or indirectly). It was easy to do as I was simply adding OpenCL to an existing code base. What then happened was simply adding a `.c` file as a module to build into my code _even when_ nothing in that c file is ever called, nor is there any reference to OpenCL anywhere else in the program, I am getting the Valgrind errors described.

Comment: Okay.  I give up.  Please report the result of lsof for your process.  Just edit your original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared objects (`.so` files) are permitted to have code that is executed as soon as the library is loaded, regardless of the use of any of the code in the library.

This is used, for example, to perform static initialization of C++ objects.

If you don't want to have valgrind complaining about things that are being done in the library behind your back, then you can run valgrind so that it generates output that can be used as a suppression file by passing in `--gen-suppressions=all`. You use the suppression output in a suppression file of your own when running against the library and it should mask out these issues.

Cases when it appears:

- If you're using C++ code and have globally scoped objects, then their constructors are called when the library is loaded
- If you add the gcc specific **attribute**((constructor)) to a function definition it gets called when the library is loaded

e.g. (C++) at a global scope:

```
#include <iostream>

class demo {
    demo() { std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; }
    ~demo() {}
};

demo ademo;
```

e.g. (C)

```
#include <stdio.h>
static void __attribute__((constructor)) my_init() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

There is a corresponding event for object destruction or `__attribute__((destructor))` on library unloading.

The ELF spec defines the presence of an `.init` and `.fini` section, which are, for libraries, the mechanism that is used to run constructor-type and destructor-type code when the library is loaded/unloaded. For a standard executable it's this, plus the getting you to `main` with the appropriate parameters.

You can explicitly change these entry points, but that's a little bit dangerous and can lead to crashes and unknown bugs. It makes more sense to hook into the mentioned supported mechanisms.

Comment: Ok, this is what I was after. Do you have a reference as to how and when this occurs? Is the code that is executed in some specific section of the ELF object? Is it easy to add this to a hypothetical library of my own (out of interest)?

Comment: I've already suppressed the Valgrind warnings, but I wanted to get to the bottom of my misunderstandings.

Comment: I've added examples of it as well as the mention of the .init/.fini ELF sections

Comment: Thank you, @Petesh - your first paragraph was what I was trying to explain.  Poorly I guess. +1

Comment: @jimmcnamara my apologies for not getting that from you!

Comment: Further reading would suggest there is a move to `.ctors` and `.dtors` sections for the constructor and destructor code (deprecating `.init` and `.fini`).

Comment: And then to `.init_array` and `.fini_array`, as per [this bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46770).

Comment: All additions which allow initialization/finalization in a manner that can support cross-language linking with uniform construction/destruction semantics.